# PHP and MySQL Session

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, session-state

we moved our website to a new server that came with a new IP address. What puzzles me; the website login sessions do not work on the new server but when I change the database IP to the old server they are working.

**MySQL Version :**

1. Old server = 5.1.58- Community
2. New server = 5.1.68 - Community

At first I thought it was a PHP error but I now believe it's not and suspect its MySQL related. Anyone who knows what might have caused this conflict?

**Debugging Error :**

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gtest\libs\products.php on line 2 Notice: Undefined index: uUserTypeID in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gtest\admin\index.php on line 50 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gtest\admin\index.php on line 52 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gtest\admin\index.php on line 52

**Line 50 :**

```
GetUserType($_SESSION['uUserTypeID'], $UserTypeID, $UserTypeDescr, $Active_Tag);
```

**Line 52 :**

```
if (($UserTypeDescr[0] == 'Admin') || ($UserTypeDescr[0] == 'Report'))
```

**Code overview :**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', True);



    session_start();
    require '../libs/database.php';
    require '../libs/users.php';
    require '../libs/products.php';
    require '../libs/quotes.php';
    require '../libs/common.php';
    require 'functions.admin.php';



    if (!($_SESSION['uAUID']) > 0)
    {
       DisplayLoginForm();

    }
    else
    {

        **GetUserType($_SESSION['uUserTypeID'], $UserTypeID, $UserTypeDescr, $Active_Tag);**

        **if (($UserTypeDescr[0] == 'Admin') || ($UserTypeDescr[0] == 'Report'))**
        {

            if (isset($_POST['eProdID']) && isset($_POST['eProdGroupID']))
            {
                $_SESSION['page'] = 'edit_product';
                $_SESSION['page_header'] = 'Edit Product';
            }
            else if (isset($_POST['eProdGroupID']))
            {
                $_SESSION['page'] = 'edit_product_group';
                $_SESSION['page_header'] = 'Edit Product Group';
            }
            else if (isset($_POST['eAUID']))
            {
                $_SESSION['page'] = 'edit_user';
                $_SESSION['page_header'] = 'Edit User';
```

Comment: It seems that you use `session_start()` multiple times. Have you checked that (also include files etc.)?

Comment: As @Pieter suggested check the `session_start()` if you have written it multiple times. And the error `Undefined index` means that `$_SESSION['uUserTypeID']` is not yet set !! and 3rd error means `$UserTypeDescr[]` array has no `key` like `$UserTypeDescr[0]` or `$UserTypeDesc` isn't defined as an array !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check over your included files/code structure.. A usual cause for this error is:

```
session_start(); 
 /* Random Code here /* 
session_start();
```

Just the duplicate lines of `session_start();`  So what I will suggest is to look over your included files/main page(s) that you are receiving this error message on, and check for more than one `session_start();`

Comment: Thanks that solved it, i used `if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }`